# The meaning of "twice too much at that"

Tags: meaning

> Sulinor rubbed his wrists again. 'We were towing our longboat
>   half-full. I steered somewhat that day.'
>
> '**What sail were you showing?**' Baeticus demanded.
>
> 'Nothing--and **twice too much at that**. But she came round when
>   Sulinor asked her, and we kept her jogging in the lee of the island. I
>   said, didn't I, that my girt-hawsers were on deck?'

This is from "The Manner of Men" by Kipling.
https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/k/kipling/rudyard/limits/chapter19.html

I do not understand the meaning  below.

What sail were you showing

and

and twice too much at that.

I am glad if some one would kindly teach me.

Answer (score 2):

It is clear from a previous paragraph

> ... the full north-easier stamped on us! Run? What else? I needed a
>   lee to clean up in.

that they were running from a storm (although there seems to be a typo: north-eas**i**er for north-eas**t**er).

So the question

> What sail were you showing?

asks how much sail was being shown *to the wind* — was being used.

The next paragraph

> Nothing — and twice too much at that. But she came round when Sulinor
>   asked her, and we kept her jogging in the lee of the island.

means that no sail was being used — but even that was too much and the ship had enough motion to be steered without using any sail.

Comment: Thank you so much, Weather Vane! The meanings are so  clear now.